# Switching branches with untracked compiled artifacts in the working tree

Tags: git

Suppose I work on `branch-1` and compile. My working tree gets populated with a bunch of binaries in various directories.

Now I want to switch to `branch-2`, but have the compiled binaries in my working tree anymore (have the exact same version of `branch-2` commit as my working tree). If I run just `git checkout branch-2`, the binaries remain in the working tree, which is a confusing situation, since HEAD points to `branch-2`  and I have binaries originating from `branch-one`.

What would be the best process for switching between branches while keeping the compiled files, more precisely:

- checkout `branch-1` and compile
- checkout `branch-2` (not have the binaries originating from `branch-1` in the working tree anymore), compile a new set of binaries
- move back to `branch-1` and restart working on `branch-1` binaries (without having to recompile)
- move back to `branch-2` and restart working on `branch-2`-produced libraries..

Comment: Why do you have binaries at all in your repository?  If you can compile them there's no value in keeping them in history.  That'd be where I would start personally; having binaries in your repo bloats it out and makes cloning it a lot slower.

Comment: have you tried with stash?

Comment: Makoto: I don't have binaries in the repository, just in the working tree.  Oswald: haven't tried stash, looking for an optimal workflow for this scenario

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is [multiple worktrees](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

If you don’t want to recompile when switching branches, you need to store the binaries somewhere. Storing them in Git somewhere is probably not a good idea, so they should be stored in the regular filesystem; the easiest way to do that is just to use different directory trees.

There are several reasons it isn’t a good idea to store the binaries in a Git commit (and stashes are a type of commit):

- It increases the size of the repository, because it stores not just the current version of the binaries but all the versions you ever commit. If you just use stashing, and you’re consistent in using `git stash pop` or `git stash drop` to get rid of the stash, then the Git garbage collector will eventually clean up the old commits, but they’ll still be around for a while. Putting them in the regular commits is even worse: the bloat will stick around forever, it’ll be easy for them to get out-of-sync with the compiled files, and they’ll be useless-at-best if anybody wants to compile your program for a different platform.
- Because of this, it’s standard to put your compiled files in the `.gitignore` file. This way, Git will pretend they aren’t there, and they won’t get in the way on `git status` calls, etc. However, part of ignoring the files means that Git won’t stash them by default, so if you regularly put your compiled files in a stash, you probably won’t want to use a `.gitignore`.
- Putting the compiled files in a stash, and not in `.gitignore`, means it’s easy to accidentally put them in a regular commit. You can avoid this if you’re careful, but it’s an easy mistake to make, and once you do you have all the problems of having binary files in your regular commits.

The primary advantage of using `git stash` for this is that it works on versions of Git before 2.6.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this.   As Oswald pointed out, the other option seems to be stashing the compiled files. Not sure what are the pros/cons multiple-worktrees vs. stashing.

Comment: Stashing is the standard way of storing the files in Git, which I said above isn’t a good idea. I’ll edit with more of an explanation of that.